# Cannot access the EC2 server - permissions problems, ssh is dead

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

One of our developers worked on a beta server and accidentally changed the permissions of the whole system (chmod /) to root. Due to that, services are unable to access files, and we can't ssh to the machine (permission denied on the key) (UPDATE: ssh is dead after reboot, probably can't start).

Does Amazon has an option to browse files / physically access the machine?

Any other creative solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create another EC2 instance and mount your EBS drive there to fix permissions. (If it's EBS based instance)